# Should I fear or embrace database triggers?

Tags: mysql, triggers

So far I have gotten by without ever using database (MariaDB/MySQL) triggers. I also have avoided foreign keys.

That fear is based on:

1. What if I forget to add a trigger to make a table make sense
2. I'd rather do it manually and just use the RDBMS as a way to store and search data
3. I can just (effectively) have a trigger in my code, simply by following DRY

However I've learnt that usually by not embracing such things I have a harder time, so I've come to you (the experts) to work out if I should change by giving you my current situation.

**Situation:**

I have a "collection" which arrives as a java-like-named package, eg "com.example.collection" which has things of several types.

"one" might be of type A, so "com.example.collection.one" is an A,

"two" might be of type B and so forth. These types are fixed (so lets suppose we only have types A, B, C and D. They are not added or anything like that).

Each of these is stored in its own table, containing details about the specific thing.

A common task is to lookup what a certain package name might be (eg "what is com.example.collection.one")

**I am faced with** either using a view, which would involve concatenate and therefore wont be easy for the optimiser to optimise OR I can create an indexing table and use triggers to keep it in order. This can be index and make lookups easy.

So my question is this: am I acting like someone when they first encounter C++ (they're unable to trust memory-management to work, much like I am not sure if I can trust TRIGGERs, even though they'd be inside transactions) - I think the answer is probably.

Is this a good use of triggers?

Lastly, what are the down-sides to triggers, the ones I listed are very weak and dubious, are there any real reasons not to use triggers? (and indeed foreign keys that delete and whatnot (provided they make sense to use of course))

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is probably better suited for dba or code review.  This is more of a discussion with no solid - single answer.

I fall on the otherside of the sprectum than you.  I have spent millions of years (before mysql enforced foreign keys) doing RDBMS.  I love them.

Regarding your fears its pretty easy to put together tools over come your short comings (or that of your organizations).

Comment: I've always trusted the RDBMS to do queries well, to choose the right index. I'd never dream of re-implementing that, but I've never given anyone access (that isn't read only) either, so triggers are code side, and because I'm not an idiot the code is inside functions called `doSomething` where it easy to add what the trigger would otherwise do.

Comment: It does remind me of the C++ thing, only people who are not fluent in C++ think memory management in C++ is an issue. Like me when I first learnt!